# Importing geos from shapely

Tags: installation, shapely, geos

I clearly have geos installed under shapely, since I downloaded "Shapely-1.4.4.tar.gz".  Also, the result can be seen in my directory in the correct path:

`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py` (the ./geos.pyc file is also there)

I get the following error:

`from shapely import geos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from shapely import geos
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 87, in <module>
    _lgeos = CDLL("geos.dll")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found`

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Could be a path problem. Where did you install the dll, and what does your PATH environment variable look like?

Comment: My PATH includes many things, one of which is  `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib`    But I'm not trying to execute from the terminal, so I'm not sure the PATH is the problem

Answer (score 3):

Shapely is not just a pure Python module, it has some "extras" (extensions written in C,C++, from the [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) library, that need to be compiled and linked  before being used, with the [Cython](http://cython.org/) module).

This compilation can be done at several stages (pip, easy_install or running python setup.py) but Windows doesn't come with a compiler by default.

You can always run the pure Python version of Shapely, but if you want the "extras" ( as geos_c.dll) use the [Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) precompiled version.

Comment: The source distributions *.tar.gz will almost never work for a Windows user. Let's advise them to always download an .exe installer from PyPI or Gohlke.

Answer (score 1):

Windows users must download an executable installer like it says in the [Shapely README](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely#installation).